# From the Feet Up meaning

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of **From the feet up**? This line is from the movie **American Hustle**.

Maybe I like him alot.
From the feed up, right?

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

> **From the feet, up** all the way to the head.

It means “completely”.

You could also say “*from the head, down*”, but the original quote sounds unusual and more dramatic.

Another idiom meaning “completely” is from “**head to tail**”.